# asp.net core Index.html not shows as default?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
namespace MyQuotesApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of your default file ?

Comment: Upgrade you packages if it not targeting to latest one 1.1 ?

Comment: default file name is index.html in wwwrool folder and upgrade all packeges...but not work

Answer (score 5):

`UseDefaultFiles` pick these files by default.

- default.htm
- default.html
- index.htm
- index.html

If that not worked in your case. You can specify name of your default file with `DefaultFilesOptions`.

```
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
```

You can also use `app.UseFileServer();`, it combines the functionality of

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**Note:**  `UseDefaultFiles` must be called before `UseStaticFiles` to serve the default file. `UseDefaultFiles` is a URL re-writer that doesn't actually serve the file. You must enable the static file middleware (`UseStaticFiles`) to serve the file.

**P.S.** also update your packages to most latest.

Comment: This actually helped me, wouldn't have figured out that my problem was the order of defaultfiles and staticfiles alone... Or would, after a lot of pain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                     template: "{controller=*YourControllerName*}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });
```